# How do I stop the next println from appearing before my scanner has received input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm building a program that asks the user some questions about houses(number, street, etc.) and I assign these inputs to Strings and integers later on. Now my problem is that I want to ask 7/8 questions, but I want the next question to appear only after the user has provided input for the previous question. The fraction of code is below here:

```
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        sc.useDelimiter("\\n");

        switch(choice){

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Geef antwoord op onderstaande vragen  en druk op ENTER na elk antwoord: ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Is de koopwoning TE KOOP of VERKOCHT? Voer een van die twee opties in: ");
            System.out.println("Voer de straatnaam van de woning in: ");
            System.out.println("Voer het huisnummer in: ");
            System.out.println("Voer de postcode in: ");
            System.out.println("Voer de plaats in: ");
            System.out.println("Voer het aantal kamers in: ");
            System.out.println("Voer de vraagprijs/koopprijs in: ");
            System.out.println("Voer het energiepeil in: ");

            String kwstate = sc.next();
            String kwstr = sc.next();
            String kwnr = sc.next(); Integer.parseInt(kwnr);
            String kwpc = sc.next();
            String kwpl = sc.next();
            int kwkamers = sc.nextInt();
            int kwprijs = sc.nextInt();
            String energie = sc.next();
```

How do I do that with this code? When I run it, it obviously displays all queations and on top of that, when I type, the input doesn't appear next to the question, but below all the questions. println is responsible for that, but using only print puts all the questions next to each other on one line in the command window. Hope I'm making sense. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a `while` with an array to the questions and answers.

Comment: If you put the code that requests input from the user BELOW the code that prints the questions, you may expect that it happens in that order too! (Note that this contains a hint to the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place each "scan" statement directly after the question that you want answered, like this:

```
System.out.println("Is de koopwoning TE KOOP of VERKOCHT? Voer een van die twee opties in: ");
String kwstate = sc.next();
System.out.println("Voer de straatnaam van de woning in: ");
String kwstr = sc.next();
System.out.println("Voer het huisnummer in: ");
String kwnr = sc.next(); 
//...
```

As a side note, you are not saving the result of `Integer.parseInt(kwnr);`
If you do not save the result to an `int` value like `int kwnrInt = Integer.parseInt(kwnr);` the result will be lost.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm using it just to check whether the user actually entered an integer. If not, I have a catch all the way below the cases for a NumberFormatException. All the cases are in a try block.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the sc.next after the println statement.

```
System.out.println("Question");
String answer = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Second Question");
```

Like that.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but it seems like something is wrong, I get an error when I enter a value voor int kwkamers. It gives an InputMisMatchException...

Comment: You need to create a new Scanner class each time you change inputs. So for .nextInt() you need to create a new instance of Scanner. I am unsure of why this is, but this workaround has worked for me. Have one scanner for lines, and one scanner for integers. Alternatively, you just parseInt() from the String.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in `Q&A` form then.

The below code just to show a skeleton logic:

```
System.out.print("Provide an integer here: ");
if sc.hasNextInt() {sc.nextInt()}
else {System.out.println("Didn't I tell you to enter integer???");}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, then this will not work:

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\n");
```

Windows uses two characters, `"\\r\\n"`, in between each line, and from my testing it appears that `Scanner` will see the `"\\r"`, and that confuses it.  This works better:

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\r?\\n");
```

which will treat either `"\\n"` or `"\\r\\n"` as a delimiter.  If you're still getting an `InputMismatchException`, this might fix that problem.  (There may be a better way to express a system-dependent newline.  It's probably best not to use a newline as a delimiter at all, and instead use `sc.nextLine()` to process the next line and any unused characters on the current line, or use some other mechanism.)